# How to access component with ref when it wrapped by withRouter in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a React component that I exported it like this:

```
class Child extends Component {
  getStatus() {
    return 'I am child!';
  }
  render() {
    return (<div>Child</div>);
  }
}

export default withRouter(Child)
```

And I have another class that needs the ref of "Child" component like this:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.childRef = createRef();
  } 

  handleLogChildStatus = () => {
    if (typeof this.childRef.current.getStatus === 'function') {
      console.log(this.childRef.current.getStatus());
    } else {
      console.log(' Can not access to child component via ref! ');
    }
  }

  render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Child ref={this.childRef} />
      <div onClick={this.handleLogChildStatus}>Log child status</div>
    </div>
  );
  }
}
```

This sample shows me I can not access to child component ref because it wrapped by withRouter HOC.

My question is How I can access to child ref component when it wrapped by nextjs withRouter>

Answer (score 0):

I think one of below should work

```
export default withRouter(Child, { withRef: true })
```

2nd option

```
 this.childComponent = React.createRef();
....
<Child wrappedComponentRef={c => (this.childComponent  = c)} />
```